# MS Access get average time

Tags: ms-access

I have this Tables:

```
button_log
    =======================================
    |ID | table_no | transaction_datetime |
    =======================================
    | 1 |    1     |  22/07/2017          |
    | 2 |    1     |  22/07/2017          |
    | 3 |    1     |  22/07/2017          |
    | 4 |    1     |  22/07/2017          |

service_time
   ===============================
   |ID | table_no | service_time |
   ===============================
   | 1 |    1     |  00:00:06    |
   | 2 |    1     |  00:00:05    |
   | 3 |    1     |  00:00:03    |
   | 4 |    1     |  00:00:10    |
```

I have this query:

```
select b.table_no, count(*) as total_call_count, sum(TimeValue(c.service_time) * 86400) as total_time from button_log b, service_time_log c where b.table_no = c.table_no and Format(b.transaction_datetime,""DD/MM/yyyy"") = '" & Date.Now.ToString("d") & "' group by b.table_no
```

but i am having this result

```
   ==========================================
   |table_no | total_call_count | total_time|
   ==========================================
   |   1     |       4          |    96     |
```

My expected result is:

```
   ==========================================
   |table_no | total_call_count | total_time|
   ==========================================
   |   1     |       4          |    24     |
```

how can i sum total_time only once per record?

Comment: You don't want to Sum total_time, you want the value to show only once? Don't use Sum, just retrieve total_time field and include it in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @June7 but then i'll have 4 rows as result.. i only need 1 result.

Comment: Okay, did you changed the example data? I thought they all had the same service_time and I wondered if it was truly representative.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the table name is wrong in the definition. You wrote service_time but use service_time_log in the query. I'll use the second one. The result was multiplied by 4 because there are 4 rows in button_log that matched the condition in the where clause. So you need to distinct the button_log table first.

```
select b.table_no, count(*) as total_call_count, sum(TimeValue(c.service_time) * 86400) as total_time
from (select distinct table_no, transaction_datetime from button_log) b, service_time_log c
where b.table_no = c.table_no and Format(b.transaction_datetime,""DD/MM/yyyy"") = '" & Date.Now.ToString("d") & "'
group by b.table_no
```

Alternative solution using join:

```
select b.table_no, count(*) as total_call_count, sum(TimeValue(c.service_time) * 86400) as total_time
from
    (select distinct table_no, transaction_datetime from button_log
    where Format(transaction_datetime,""DD/MM/yyyy"") = '" & Date.Now.ToString("d") & "') b
    inner join service_time_log c on b.table_no = c.table_no
group by b.table_no
```

Comment: To clarify somewhat using proper query terms, the original query used a _cross join_ (comma separated list of tables without any join keyword) which takes _every combination_ of rows from each table.  In this case, 4 button_log rows * 4 service_time rows, so it sums the same values 4 times.

Comment: Actually, it's possible to do the join properly without the `join` keyword because the join condition is provided in the where clause. See that `where b.table_no = c.table_no`.

Comment: I was just pointing out that this is called a cross join and although the WHERE condition filters out extra rows, the default behavior is to still product the full Cartesian Product of the table rows... every combination of rows.  More advanced DBMS like SQL Server, Oracle, etc. which have advanced execution plan optimization can make this issue trivial, but in my testing with Access, it is not necessarily so smart.  It will perform the full cross join before filtering records based on the WHERE.  Explicitly specifying the join type (INNER JOIN would work here) can be more efficient.

Comment: It would be more efficient overall by putting the criteria on b.transaction_datetime in the inner subquery, then doing an INNER JOIN.  For the small sample data set it's negligible, but if the tables get large with many dates and times and table_id values, the current query produces unnecessary row combinations which are then just filtered out.

Comment: I agree that more advanced DBMS can optimized these kind of query. Also using proper join clause is easier to understand when the number of tables in the join are large (like 10 tables or more) because the where clause is not polluted with the join condition. I edited my answer based on your suggestion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't complicate date/time handling, so try this:

```
"Select
    button_log.table_no,
    Count(*) As total_call_count,
    (Select Sum(service_time_log.service_time) * 86400 
    From service_time_log 
    Where service_time_log.table_no = button_log.table_no) As total_time 
From 
    button_log
Where
    button_log.transaction_datetime = #" & DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#
Group By
    button_log.table_no"
```

Comment: You say not to complicate date/time handling, but then why the complicated string conversion for today's date?  Why not just call the Date() function within the SQL statement, like  `button_log.transaction_datetime = Date()`?

Comment: You are probably correct, but I was not sure if that would work in the unknown environment.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT button_log.table_no, Count(transaction_datetime) AS CountOfTransDate, Q1.TotalTime
FROM (SELECT table_no, Sum(TimeValue([service_time])*86400) AS TotalTime FROM service_time_log GROUP BY table_no) AS Q1 
INNER JOIN button_log ON Q1.table_no = button_log.table_no
WHERE button_log.transaction_datetime=Date()
GROUP BY button_log.table_no, Q1.TotalTime;`

Your example shows international date format. Since my db uses Access standard (U.S.) format I did not have to manipulate the dates. Adjust as needed for your situation.

However, since the service_time_log does not have a date value, its records cannot be filtered by date so how does the TotalTime correlate to the button_log date? Will each table_no have only one date?

Your example shows 4 records in each table for table_no 1. Will there always be equal number of records in each table for each table_no?